# Sort rows of data frame according to aggregate function of the columns

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame with two columns, `id` and `value` and more than 100k observations.

There are about 1000 distinct ids.

I would like to create two new data frames with the same data of the original one but with the rows sorted according to the following criteria.

For one data frame, if two rows `r1` and `r2` have got ids `id1` and `id2` respectively, and if the number of rows with `id = id1` is smaller than the number or rows with `id = id2`, then `r1` should appear before `r2`.

For the other data frame, if two rows `r1` and `r2` have got ids `id1` and `id2` and the maximum `value` of a row with `id = id1` is smaller than the maximum value of a row with `id = id2`, when `r1` should appear before `r2`.

The two orderings are defined *according to aggregate functions of the columns*, so a solution for creating such an ordering would allow one to create a far greater class of orderings.

How can I efficiently build such orderings in R?

EDIT:
This is my code, it works but it slow and long. I wonder if there is a smarter and quicker way of doing it.

```
library(hashmap)
a <- read.table(filename, header = T)
aggregate_values <- unlist(lapply(unique(a[[1]]), function(x) max(a[a[[1]] == x,2])))
id_to_aggregate_value <- hashmap(unique(a[[1]]), aggregate_values)
aggregate_values_columns <- id_to_aggregate_value[[a[[1]]]]
a <- cbind(a, aggregate_values_columns)
a <- a[order(a[,3]),]
```

Comment: This kind of operation is what the `data.table` package excels in.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know, I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

# Make a similar table as yours with ~1000 ids and 100k rows
df <- tibble(
  id = rnorm(n = 1E5, mean = 1000, sd = 150) %>% as.integer(),
  value = runif(1E5, 500, 1500)
)

# How many unique id's? Should be around 1000...
length(unique(df$id))
[1] 1052     

# First question, show infrequent id's first
df_sort_by_id_freq <- df %>%
  add_count(id) %>%
  arrange(n, id)

# Second question, show id's with smallest max first
df_sort_by_max <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(id_max = max(value)) %>%
  arrange(id_max, id, value)
```